# How to arrange a sloppy heatmap r

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap of p-values with the outcome of a pairwise.wilcox.test. So, after performing the test, I reshape the outcome:

```
test <- pairwise.wilcox.test(world$mean, world$con, p.adjust.method ="bonferroni",conf.level = 0.95)
test.result <- melt (test[[3]],na.rm=T)
```

The outcome is the following:

```
     X1       X2        value
1    europe   africa 7.216273e-20
2  namerica   africa 2.694228e-23
3  samerica   africa 1.001953e-01
4      asia   africa 3.515077e-66
5    europe   europe           NA
6  namerica   europe 6.551144e-02
7  samerica   europe 2.615654e-05
8      asia   europe 2.148064e-09
9    europe namerica           NA
10 namerica namerica           NA
11 samerica namerica 4.894171e-10
12     asia namerica 3.642124e-02
13   europe samerica           NA
14 namerica samerica           NA
15 samerica samerica           NA
16     asia samerica 5.999172e-25
```

Then I run a ggplot2 script to get the heatmap:

```
test.result$X1 <- factor(test.result$X1, levels = c("europe", "namerica", "samerica", "asia"))
test.result$X2 <- factor(test.result$X2, levels = c("europe", "namerica", "samerica","asia"))

test.result$value<-cut(test.result$value, breaks=c(-Inf,0.001,0.05,1),right=F)

ggplot(data = test.result, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=test.result$value),color="white") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues",name="p-Val")
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
                                   size = 12, hjust = 1)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

The outcome is the following figure:
[image]

As you can see the figure is not sorted in the diagonal, is kind of sloppy... I dont know how to arrange correctly the figure in order to get all the p values in the diagonal. Thanks for your help

The figure that I'm looking for is like this:
[image]

Comment: It is not clear, how does expected plot should look like?

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain myself correctly. I want the figure to be represented in the diagonal. Like a pairwise plot!

Comment: I still do not get get what you want. What do you want on the diagonal?

Comment: Ok, I just edit my question with an image of the figure that im looking for... Thanks!

Comment: You need to change the orders of your factors. `test.result$X1 <- factor(test.result$X1, levels = c("europe", "namerica", "samerica", "asia"))` and the same for X2.

Comment: Thanks, Swarch! But as you can see above I'm still having problmes to get what I need!

Comment: Im getting same result even if in test.result$X2 I remove "asia" from factors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?:

Calling your data `tr`:

```
tr = structure(list(X1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("asia", "europe", 
"namerica", "samerica"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("africa", 
"europe", "namerica", "samerica"), class = "factor"), value = c(7.216273e-20, 
2.694228e-23, 0.1001953, 3.515077e-66, NA, 0.06551144, 2.615654e-05, 
2.148064e-09, NA, NA, 4.894171e-10, 0.03642124, NA, NA, NA, 5.999172e-25
)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```

Swarch's comment was correct in that we need the factors to have the same levels/same order. The comment didn't quite work because `africa` was omitted. Fixing that:

```
lev = c("europe", "namerica", "samerica", "asia", "africa")
tr$X1 <- factor(tr$X1, levels = lev)
trX2 <- factor(tr$X2, levels = lev)
```

We can now make a plot. Some corrections here

1. **never** use `data$column` inside `aes()` - use unquoted column names.
2. if you specify `fill = value` in the top `ggplot()` call, no need to reiterate it for the `geom_tile()` layer.
3. your `value` seems to be continuous. `scale_fill_brewer` implies a discrete scale, so cannot be used here. It seems fine without, but you could also try `scale_fill_distiller`.
4. the code in your question was missing a `+`.

This code works:

```
ggplot(data = tr, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) +
    geom_tile(color = "white") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 45,
        vjust = 1,
        size = 12,
        hjust = 1
    )) +
    coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Also note that the exact diagonal of 1's is missing here (unlike in your `mtcars` example) because it is missing from your data. That is, `africa` is completely absent from `X1` and `asia` is completely absent from `X2`. If you want to plot those tiles, you will need to augment your data with those rows.